# JavaFX StackPane bounds not updated

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

When I run the following program

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Test1 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {       
        Pane topPane = new Pane();      
        Scene scene = new Scene(topPane, 600, 400);

        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        Label l1 = new Label("1 2");
        Ellipse e1 = new Ellipse(100, 50);
        e1.setOpacity(0.5);
        sp.getChildren().addAll(l1, e1);            
        e1.radiusXProperty().bind(l1.widthProperty());
        e1.radiusYProperty().bind(l1.heightProperty());         
        topPane.getChildren().add(sp);
        sp.relocate(200, 100);

        sp.setStyle("-fx-border-color: RED;");              

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            //l1.setText("123");
            //l1.setText("1 2");
        });             

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();       
    }
}
```

I get a red box surrounding the text label only, but when I uncomment the two lines inside the Platform.runLater() block above, I get a red box surrounding the outer ellipse, which is what I want.
So it seems to me the layout bounds of the stack pane is not set correctly from the model description, since the bounds are determined only from the label control. But when I force an invalidation in Platform.runLater() the layout bounds are where they should be.
Why is this happening and how do I prevent it? I would like to be able to just specify my model/graph and then it should render correctly on the first show, or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this `sp.requestLayout();` after `stage.Show();`

Comment: This works, but IMO, for this case, an explicit layout request call should not be necessary and the fact that it is required is a minor bug in the JavaFX implementation, for which the original question asker may wish to [file a bug report](http://bugreport.java.com).

Comment: Thanks Elltz and jewelsea, the sp.requestLayout() worked. Would it be possible to explain what is happening here, that is, any idea of why this is needed? It is more than a minor nuisance to remember to do this on every StackPane I use in this way..

Comment: if you remove the binding of ellipse & label it works, if you set an initial `setPrefSize(50.0,50.0);` for the stackpane it also works, so i feel it has to do with it since its radius was shrunk to the size of the label hence that effect, so is it still a bug sir?@jewelsea , well J18434, that shouldn't happen as StackPane should size itself after recording the largest child + padding, unless restricted which you didn't but that didn't happen which means it was confused at the end of things, so a request layout brought it back to its required sense, but bounds say otherwise, so guess its a bug

Comment: @j18434 was just to notify you. well like great Sir jewelsea :-) said file a bug report and see how it goes, and don't forget to upvote and accept

Comment: As suggested by @jewelsea, I have just reported this as a bug with Oracle. The bug id is JDK-8137252, at url http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8137252